# Problems returning a widget on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class PerguntaApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
    void responder() {
      print("Pergunta respondida");
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final perguntas = [
      "Qual e a sua cor favorita?"
      "Qual e o seu animal favorito?"
    ];

    @override
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Perguntas"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children:<Widget> [
            Text(perguntas[0]),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Resposta 1"),
              onPressed: responder,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Resposta 2"),
              onPressed: responder,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Resposta 3"),
              onPressed: responder,
            ),
          ],
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem it's when i try to `return MaterialApp`, it's showing a red line on return saying that expects an identifier.
I don't know if it's indentation, ponctuation, i've tried but i didn't worked thought.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `@override`. The one above `return MaterialApp(`

You only need to put @override above a function. You never need one above a return statement. :)

Comment: No problem - could you mark my answer as correct please if you can!